# Calculate the resistance of R

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

A cabin contains 2 electronic appliances: a radio that requires 10 miliamperes of current at 9V and a clock that requires 20 miliamperes at 15V.

A 15 V battery with negligible internal resistance supplies the electrical energy to operate the radio and clock.

A resistor (R) is in series with the radio and both of those are in parallel with the clock.

Find the resistance of the resistor.

What I have got:

I found the resistance of the radio which is:

```
R = 9/0.01
R = 900 ohms (radio)
```

And the resistance of the clock which is:

```
R = 15/0.02
R = 750 ohms
```

What I am trying to figure out is how do I calculate the resistance of R now that I know the resistance of both the clock and the radio?

P.S I am a beginner at this topic and NO, I am not trying to get you to spit answers out for me. I just want to understand my problems so just give me a hint if you can. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The potential difference maintained by the battery across the radio-resistor series combination is 15V. The radio requires a potential drop of 9V and a current of 10 mA. Hence the rest of the 6V will be across the resistor which is in series with the radio. As you know the potential difference across the resistor and the current through it, you can find the resistance.

Comment: I understand that R = V/I but my question is how would I find out the voltage across the resistor without knowing about the current and vice versa?

Comment: Voltage across the resistor has been calculated without considering the current through it.

Comment: So according to your answer, the Voltage across the resistor is 6V?

Comment: Yes, according to my answer, the Voltage across the resistor is 6V.

Comment: Even if I do have a voltage of 6; I still require the current in order to find the resistance. I know the resistance of both the clock and the radio. If the resistance of the radio is 900 ohms and the voltage 6V then the current of that will be 0.007 A. How is this supposed to work?

Comment: But the voltage across the resistor is 6V, not across the radio. Across the radio it is 9V as given in the problem.